# remove css if sidebar is not present on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

this is a bit weird for a background color application, I have this main structure

```
<section class="main-row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="primary" class="col-sm-12 content-area">
</div>
<div id="secondary" class="col-sm-4 sidebar widget-area">
<div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

and on the main row I applied a css editing the media queries to adjust the width along the way:

```
.main-row {
  padding: 70px 0;
/* background: linear-gradient( to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 62%, #f0f0f0 38%, #f0f0f0 100% ); */
}
```

now this works if there is a sidebar, but if full page I want to remove the background to make it solid white only, Is it possible in php? I just want to have the sidebar to have a solid background extending full height and width, but the container and row is set to adjust the content to only 1170px, but I want the sidebar to be full height and color to the right if sidebar is right and to the left if sidebar is left.

Comment: It is bit unclear to me. Can you share the page you are working on? Maybe a demo.

Comment: here is the link you can try to click on the slider it will go to the full page with the background I want to remove http://dev.webdesignagents.com.ph/clients/muscleandfitnessph/www/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `body_class` filter to add a class to the body if the template uses a sidebar (replace `my-sidebar-template.php` with your sidebar-template name):

```
add_filter('body_class', 'sidebar_template_class');
function sidebar_template_class($classes){
  if(get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID()) == 'my-sidebar-template.php')
      $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';

  return $classes;
}
```

Use CSS to remove the background for any `.main-row`s that are descendants of `body.has-sidebar`:

**CSS**

```
.main-row {
    background: linear-gradient( to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 62%, #f0f0f0 38%, #f0f0f0 100% );
}
.has-sidebar .main-row{
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: _Classy_ solution! I like it.

Comment: tried adding this to my functions.php and now my wordpress is white, unfortunately my ftp client is giving me an error 530 FTP Access Denied, you have been temporarily blocked due to suspicious FTP activity (121.58.247.2)

Comment: Apologies, I left a typo. See the update. (Semi colon ending the `$classes[] = ` line).

Comment: tried the code unfortunately it still displays the ackground my sidear name is just sidear.php the call is just  <?php if (($sidebar_position == 'right') || ($sidebar_position == 'left')) : ?>
                    <div id="secondary" class="col-sm-4 sidebar widget-area">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <?php get_sidebar();?>
                        </div>

Comment: You need to change `my-sidebar-template.php` for the path to your template. I.E. `template-parts/sidebar.php`

Comment: here is the code inside single.php does this affect the code you gave? <?php if ($sidebar_position == 'left') : ?>
    <section class="main-row  sidebar-left">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="primary" class="col-sm-8 content-area">
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ($sidebar_position == 'right') : ?>
    <section class="main-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="primary" class="col-sm-8 content-area">
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ($sidebar_position == 'full') : ?>
    <section class="main-row">

Comment: I just have sidebar.php in the folder no template-parts, should I create this?

Comment: @RommelBagtas No, having it a template parts folder is optional. Print out the value of `get_page_template_slug(get_the_ID())` to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out with a more practical solution:

```
.sidebar .inner {
 border-left: none;
margin-left: 59px;
padding-left: 30px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
margin-right: -3000px;
padding-right: 3000px;
padding-bottom: 3000px;
margin-bottom: -3000px;
margin-top: -130px;
padding-top: 50px;
```

}